# Why does a Visual Studio generated WSDL not specify soap:operation elements (missing wsdl:binding element)

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, soap, wsdl

Background: I've inherited two web service projects which were developed by the same contractors.

Problem: One of the project's WSDL file loads into SoapUI to generate a test suite but the other doesn't. I think that the second one doesn't because it specifies its operations without referencing the "soap:operation".

Here's the declaration of a API method from the WSDL that imports into SoapUI:

```
<wsdl:operation name="getDutyPreferences">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IRT2015WS_Web/getDutyPreferences" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

and here is a declaration from the WDSL which won't import into SoapUI:

```
<wsdl:operation name="Login">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IRT2015WS_Web/Login" message="tns:IRT2015WS_Web_Login_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IRT2015WS_Web/LoginResponse" message="tns:IRT2015WS_Web_Login_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Both WSDL were downloaded from http://localhost:{port}/SERVICE_NAME.svc?wsdl

Does anyone have any idea why the methods have such different declarations?

**UPDATE**
I've noticed that the  elements (which are what I need to see) are in the  element in the working WSDL file: in the problematic file this element is missing.  I've updated the question title to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the above one is WSDL and the next one is single WSDL.The following picture shows two WSDL provided by WCF:
[image]

Svcutil can generate proxy classes based on the first link.When going cross technologies ，the singleWsdl option is the safest to use.For example, in Java, you can use the WSDL 2java of CXF 3.0 to generate Java packages based on single WSDL, and you can use jax-ws to create connections.They can all generate proxy classes.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts but the <wsld:binding> element is missing from both the WSDL and single WSDL file.(See the UPDATE section of the question).